# How to dynamically use $push in mongo query

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I've got a document that has the following format:

```
{ 
"Students" : {
    "Week1" : {
        "Monday" : [

        ], 
        "Tuesday" : [

        ], 
        "Wednesday" : [

        ], 
        "Thursday" : [

        ], 
        "Friday" : [

        ], 
        "Saturday" : [

        ], 
        "Sunday" : [

        ]
    }, 
    "Week2" : {
        "Sunday" : [

        ], 
        "Monday" : [

        ], 
        "Tuesday" : [

        ], 
        "Wednesday" : [

        ], 
        "Thursday" : [

        ], 
        "Friday" : [

        ], 
        "Saturday" : [

        ]
    }, 
    "Week3" : {
        "Sunday" : [

        ], 
        "Monday" : [

        ], 
        "Tuesday" : [

        ], 
        "Wednesday" : [

        ], 
        "Thursday" : [

        ], 
        "Friday" : [

        ], 
        "Saturday" : [

        ]
    }, 
    "Week4" : {
        "Sunday" : [

        ], 
        "Monday" : [

        ], 
        "Tuesday" : [

        ], 
        "Wednesday" : [

        ], 
        "Thursday" : [

        ], 
        "Friday" : [

        ], 
        "Saturday" : [

        ]
    }, 
    "Week5" : {
        "Sunday" : [

        ], 
        "Monday" : [

        ], 
        "Tuesday" : [

        ], 
        "Wednesday" : [

        ], 
        "Thursday" : [

        ], 
        "Friday" : [

        ], 
        "Saturday" : [

        ]
    }
  }
}
```

I want to push some elements into Students.Week1.Monday dynamically using Week1 as a variable. So I thought to build it like this:

```
var dbNames = ['Zoe', 'Billy', 'Joey'];
var week = Week1; // week is dynamic entry
var query1 = {};
query1['Students.' + week + '.Monday'] = '$in: ' + dbNames;
Programs.update({ _id: teacherid }, { $push: query1 });
```

I'm messing this up. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can create Objects Dynamically to solve the problem

```
var query = {};
var week = "DYNAMIC_VAL"; // Replace this
var day = "Monday";  // Dynamic Day
var dbNames = ['Zoe', 'Billy', 'Joey'];
query['Students'] = {};
query['Students'][week] = {};

// query['Students'][week][day] = { '$in': dBNames } // As per your query.
// but it should not work,
// if you want to push all elements of dbNames then you can use $each instead of $in

query['Students'][week][day] = { '$each': dBNames };


//console.log(JSON.stringify(query, null, 2));

Programs.update({ _id: teacherid }, { $push: query }, callback);
```

Comment: I think you cant use $in here, if you want to push all dbNames then you need to use $each instead of $in

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the $each instead of $in. I was thinking of the $pull operator. The way you're building the object gives an error that claims that it can't apply $push to a non-array. My method of building the object gives no error, but what I missed (and you got right) was the value to the object should be { '$each': dbNames }.